# Break main issue GDB

Tags: c++, gdb, program-entry-point, break

I am currently new to C++ and handling GDB.

I have used the "break main" commands and I get the following output

> Breakpoint 1 at 0x14fc0.

How can I know what to do now that I have this?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish

Comment: You would have to run the program with `run` command. The real question is what you are going to do when it breaks there :)

Comment: You may need to ensure that you have compiled and linked with the `-g` option (at minimum); the bare address given suggests that maybe you didn't include that.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you really need to spend some time with a gdb tutorial or reference, unfortunately good ones are not easy to find. This is probably one of the better introduction I have found [A Guide to GDB](http://www.lashi.org/writing/guide_to_gdb_1.1.pdf). This is a good cheat sheet: [GDB cheat sheet](http://darkdust.net/files/GDB%20Cheat%20Sheet.pdf).

But if you really serious about learning gdb "The Art of Debugging" from No Starch Press is probably the best book out there and is way better than any of the online material I have ever found.